Sign Conventions for Electron Affinity and Electron Gain Enthalpy
In some of the books, negative sign is used for an exothermic Electron Affinity. But in others, a positive sign indicates an exothermic Electron Affinity. Now if we adopt the first sign convention of using negative sign for an exothermic electron affinity, what will be the sign for electron gain enthalpy of this.
Because in some books, it is said the sign of electron gain enthalpy and electron affinity is opposite. But they have used the later sign convention of using positive sign for exothermic electron affinity. This difference in sign conventions confuses me and I can't decide which sign to use for electron gain enthalpy.

Usually we consider energy absorbed by a system as negative and energy released as postive. So, it is actually correct ro represent exothermic EA in positive in chemistry. But if you consider the system to be the surrounding and not the atom, then the sign changes.
Also sign of EA is same as sign of Electron gain enthalpy unless you change the system midway your considerations.
So, I suggest you to use positive for exothermic.
